# Improve speed tool for database (Laravel / mysql / phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel based web portal where I'm having millions of data from database.
The problem I'm having is very low reading speed from database which causing very slow page load.
I have tried indexing, optimisation of queries also tried Laravel cache nothing worked for me.
I am looking for any third party paid tools which can help me to overcome this issue.
My Current database – Gen 5, vCore 1

Comment: Start by finding the slowest queries via the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Optimize MySQL configuration using MySQLTuner or https://releem.com MySQL Performance Tuning as a Service.
2. Find and optimize slow queries.

If there are no optimization opportuninties then move db on another server.